# connect json with extjs

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

In my sample login form, I am trying to connect to json and get the result ie., true, if username and password matches, else false.

**json** (*exists in my project folder*)

```
{
 "form": {
    "login": [
    {
      "username": "venkat",
      "password": "123"
    },
    {
      "username": "admin",
      "password": "345"
    }
  ]
}
```

I created a function like below. But I don't know what to do next. The sencha documentation has methods like ajax, proxy for MVC architecture, which I am not using.

```
function checkJson(username, password){
    //What should I write here?
    //Return true, if match
    //else false
}
```

Comment: Where does this json exit?

Comment: @Izhaki In my project folder..

Comment: You can't do anything with a static JSON file because it's static. You need to process it (PHP, Java, .NET, other) to take the information and get a result.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Can we use REST to do that? (I am not familiar with it, just asking)

Comment: Well, you can get it with a simple ajax call. But do you seriously plan to return user passwords to the client side - every user will be able to see these with a click of a button. You should really send the password/user name to the server to do the checks.

Comment: @Izhaki Sorry for asking noob question,  instead of checking at server, can we do the same using REST?

Comment: Please have a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810340/load-new-view-after-the-loginin-extjs-4-mvc/14812218#14812218) to see how to implement login mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Never write down unencrypted passwords. And also never send them via teh interwebs!

You can process your JSON in extjs like this (that is the question right?):

```
function checkJson(jsonString){
    var json = Ext.decode(jsonString);

    //json.form.login[0].username;
    //json.form.login[0].password;
}
```

But what @Izhaki said. This is bad javascript and these kind of checks should be done on the server-side.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to do this.. Can it be done using REST or without using server? (which is what I am interested in). I mean server will be there but I am thinking of using something like Web service(which I think is REST) to do json calls.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with REST so I can't help you with this one but I guess you need a server to send your requests.

Comment: +1 you are right, that I need server support, which I am aware of.  Any way I am searching about it now :).